# Getting cpu usage same every time.

Tags: command-line, cpu

When I execute following command to get cpu usage , I get nice + user cpu usage.

```
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'
```

**Output:**

```
14.5
```

Here I am getting problem is that the output depends on top command thus it doesn't change instantly as top command. So I am not getting correct cpu instantly. It gives same output and not changing.

I want to get realtime cpuusage in output. Please help me to improve my command.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Try running the command prepended with `time`.  On my system it only takes 0.165s.

Comment: Please give me edited command.

Comment: Try: `time (top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}' )`

Comment: no diffrence in output,after tested in different systems

Comment: You get `14.5` every time?  Before you edited your question, I thought you were saying that the command was taking too long to run, not that it was giving the same output every time.

Comment: Is this on Linux?

Comment: Don't the answers you have received answer your question? If they don't, please [edit] and explain what's missing. If they do, please remember to accept one of them.

Answer (score 17):

You're right, `top` appears to give incorrect CPU usage on first iteration. You can work around this issue like this:

```
top -b -n2 | grep "Cpu(s)"|tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2 + $4}'
```

This will of course take twice as much time, but it will work anyway.

If you still want it work faster, you can use `-d` option, e.g. for 1-second total period of measurement use half of it:

```
top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | grep "Cpu(s)"|tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2 + $4}'
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/436499/134517  also it will take much more than twice the time as it will take roughly one second instead of nearly none.

Comment: In addition to the comment by altendky, see also [answer by terdon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90904/27672) for explanation why the issue is there in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Technically the first `top` doesn't always output the same value; it just outputs the average CPU load since last boot. Because `top` uses the delta of `/proc/stat` stats to calculate the CPU load, the first value is calculated while comparing against zero, yielding incorrect (but WAD) result.

If you don't want to use `top`, you can directly parse `/proc/stat`:

```
cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS="" '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5) "%"}'
```

It's also faster and more accurate this way.

You can test it with `stress`:

```
stress -c 1 -q &
```

And do

```
killall stress
```

after.

Comment: Nice. And if your command is placed in a file called 'cpu', then `watch` can be run on it: `watch -n1 "bash ./cpu"`

Comment: Your awk script to parse `/proc/stat` is pretty cool but it appear to have the same drawback as top's first iteration: It outputs the average CPU load since last boot, not the current one.

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on @Ruslan's answer, `top` splits CPU usage between user, system processes and `nice` processes, we want the sum of the three. So, we can run `top` in `b`atch mode which allows us to parse its output. However, as explained [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619), the 1st iteration of `top -b` returns the percentages since boot, we therefore need at least two iterations (`-n 2`) to get the current percentage. To speed things up, you can set the `d`elay between iterations to `0.01`:

```
top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^%Cpu' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use this one based on `ps` output :

```
ps aux  | awk 'BEGIN { sum = 0 }  { sum += $3 }; END { print sum }
```

Comment: I have this command: `ps -Ao PCPU | awk '{total += $1} END {print total/8}'` where 8 is the number of CPU cores. Note that  different `ps` command implementation has different options format. The idea is simple, adding %CPU of all processes and dividing by number of CPU cores.

Comment: This always gives the same number. I see no load variation eventhough HTOP shows lots of CPU variation.

Answer (score 0):

Use watch command or for loop in shell,

i.e `watch -n1 "top -b -n1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | awk '{print \$2 + \$4}'"`

Comment: Same thing Happens with watch

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about the CPU usage? The [load average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) is a much better indicator:

```
cat /proc/loadavg
```

If you really need the CPU usage, parsing `/proc/stat` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Load average is basically a time integral of CPU usage (divided by time). Why would you say an integral characteristic is much better indicator [of everything] than a differential one when they have completely different use cases? Also, `/proc/stat` doesn't give CPU usage as it is, one has to read it twice with some time between reads and do some calculations to get CPU usage. This is just what `top` does.

Comment: I can't math, so I have to admit I don't really understand the difference between integral and differential :/ "Load average is basically a time integral of CPU usage" - is it really? AFAIK a process that hangs in the D state causes a load increase, but no CPU usage. "Why would you say..." - OP doesn't say what he *really* wants to accomplish, so to be honest, I just assume he wants to measure his system load and thought that the CPU usage would be the best indicator for this, so I directed him to load average.

Comment: From your link: "Systems calculate the load average as the exponentially damped/weighted moving average of the load number." and "the system load is a measure of the amount of computational work". D state isn't taking any computational work. What is taking is the processes which use CPU time. So average load is _basically_ percentage of time CPU wasn't idle for some period of time (say, minutes to tens of minutes). And CPU usage is percentage of time CPU isn't idle at time scale of milliseconds - i.e. updated every time you read it and reflecting _current_ state.

Answer (score -2):

Using `sar` command

```
sar 1 10
```

That means: get 10 times result in every second