# terminate 'top' command after one iteration - Unix

Tags: top

I want to execute the `top` command just one iteration, so I can capture the process output programmatically. If I just execute `top`, it won't return unless I kill the terminal. Thus, I only need to execute it once and return. How can I do it?
Edit: I'm running the `top` command from `Java: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");`.

Comment: It's helpful to mention that you're calling it from java

Comment: then why don't use other tools like `ps`, reading procfs...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As least with Linux/procps top you probably want both `-b` (to switch it to batch mode) and `-n 1` (to only run one iteration).

```
top -b -n 1
```

I suggest reading the manual page via `man top`, it documents these options.

Not to mention, depending on the goal, there may be better tools to use (e.g., `ps` or some library available in your programming language).

Comment: Also, note that `top` needs at least [two iterations](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90904/22222)  to get CPU percentages correctly.